# Add field(s) to menu link?

Tags: 8, entities, navigation

Is there a way to add field(s) to menu links in Drupal 8? Like an image field to output above certain links?

Comment: Could you specify the use case a bit ? The image field should come from a related node somehow or ?

Comment: When creating a menu link in the menu admin, there would be a field for attaching an image to it, for rendering in say, a mega menu.

Comment: Ah, i see. So you need something like https://www.drupal.org/project/menuimage or https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_icons for D8.

Comment: @OlegVidenov I only see D7 versions for both of those modules...

Comment: yes, for now I also don't see any D8 ports of those modules as well.

Comment: @Kevin you can do it like they did in [menuimage.module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/menuimage/tree/menuimage.module) which is just a hook_form_alter and then do a [validate and/or summit](https://westweb-solutions.com/blog/drupal-8-how-attach-custom-validatesubmit-existing-form)

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your custom module:

```
function my_module_entity_base_field_info(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'menu_link_content') {
    $fields['menu_link_image'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('image')
      ->setLabel(t('Menu link image'))
      ->setDescription(t('Upload the image related to this menu item'))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array('type' => 'string', 'weight' => 0));

    return $fields;
  }
}
```

Then use `hook_update_n` to update the schema of the `menu_link_content_data` table. Run `update.php`, flush caches and the new field should appear on all the Add/Edit menu item form.

---

In case someone wants to simply add a text field, boolean etc, simply edit `BaseFieldDefinition::create('image')` and change it to `BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')` or `BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')` etc