# Adding new text field to drupal 8 menu

Tags: theming, hooks

I am trying to add a new text field to the menu in Drupal 8, and I have done it using the instruction in the following post:

[Add field(s) to menu link?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232204/add-fields-to-menu-link)

```
function my_module_entity_base_field_info(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface 
$entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'menu_link_content') {
    $fields['location'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Location'))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', ['label' => 'hidden', 'type' => 'string', 'weight' => 0, ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array('type' => 'string', 'weight' => 0));

    return $fields;
  }
}
```

But I am not sure how to go about using hook_update_n to update the schema to reflect this change.

```
function menu_link_content_update_8201() { 'what do I put here to add the new field that I created'? }
```

I was able to workaround this issue by manually adding the `location` column in the mysql db and I can see the field showing up in the menu link editor and able to load and save it just fine in the cms UI.

But then I am not sure how to access this field in the twig file.

Any help would be grateful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You only need an update hook if you want that your module can be updated on production sites already using the module. If you write a new module or the module is still in development you can simply reinstall the module. If you have data you want to keep during development use `drush entity-updates` after changing the code of the installed module.