# Update drupal module with existing custom changes

Tags: 8

I am new to drupal and am wondering when I update a drupal module, say the menu module for example.

If I have some existing custom changes to the module, is it ok to just update the module and it will retain all my custom changes once the update is completed?

Or is it going to overwrite all my custom changes and I would have to "re-do" them or will it actually create a merge conflict during the update?

I am not entirely sure the practice in updating modules where there are custom changes added to it so any insight would be helpful.  This is for drupal 8.

Thanks!

Comment: There is little if any reason to be hacking core modules and is likely achievable using the API to get what you want. It will be overridden every time you update code. That’s how it works. You should maintain any patches with composer and composer patch workflow.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to hack modules or core directly, because when you update drupal and modules your changes will get lost.  If you have some valuable changes or corrections that others might benefit from its best to submit a patch to the issue queue of the module and if maintainer accepts them you benefit as well.

If maintainer does not decide to use your changes you can also consider making your own module or perhaps with a custom theme you can  accomplish what you want to do.  Drupal has a great system in place to override parts of code with your own logic without hacking core or contributed modules.

If you actually decide to keep those changes as hacks you will have to do your own merge confict resolution as drupal internal update process or even drush updating will not do it for you.

Comment: Thanks!  So I was following this post https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232204/add-fields-to-menu-link in order to add a new field to menu link, I tried to use the hook in another file outside of the module but then it wouldn't create a new field for me so I placed the code directly in the module/core, if that's the wrong approach what could I change?  If I need to create a new module how do I go about creating a custom one on top of the existing druapl 8 menu module?

Comment: well if you followed the instructions there post a new question with what you did or maybe what you are trying to accomplish and maybe you get help on it or there could be an alternative way of doing it